# Profiler for twig template

Tags: php, html, symfony, templates, twig

I'm starting to optimize my website which is currently still with dev environment in Symfony2.

I have one page which is quite wierd. The page load in ~1000ms and the twig template takes ~900ms based on Symfony profiler.

I've looked at the twig template but it's quite big (lots of loops, include templates etc...)

I would like to know what takes so many times in my template, so I'm looking for a way to profile this templates. Is this possible and how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Symfony 2.4, in your twig template:

```
{% stopwatch "foo" %}
   ... some things that gets timed
{% endstopwatch %}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, foo is added directly into Symfony profiler. Thanks !